# Map panning using mouse wheel in OpenLayers 3+

Tags: openlayers

How to achieve functionality that user could scroll through map by pressing mouse wheel and dragging map like he can do it by pressing left mouse button?

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll through map"? Zoom in/out? Please edit your question and explain this.

Comment: You mean dragging (pan) map up and down? What about left and right? What about other directions in between?

Comment: I do not mean zoom. I mean navigating through map world directions wise: east, south, west, north. Like in most map applications you press left mouse button and you navigate left/right/up/down through the layer. This is the only way I understand action "scroll" and do not see how it could be understood otherwise. Feel free to edit the question if you think my phrasing is wrong.

Comment: In GIS map world this is called map panning. Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139932/openlayer-pan-using-only-mouse-middle-button

Comment: Now I will know:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom DragPan interaction with custom condition

```
import { defaults as defaultInteractions, DragPan } from "ol/interaction";
import { noModifierKeys } from "ol/events/condition";

const primaryMiddle = function(mapBrowserEvent) {
  const pointerEvent = mapBrowserEvent.pointerEvent;
  return pointerEvent.isPrimary && pointerEvent.button === 1;
}

  interactions: defaultInteractions({ dragPan: false }).extend([
    new DragPan({
      condition: function(mapBrowserEvent) {
        return (
          noModifierKeys(mapBrowserEvent) && primaryMiddle(mapBrowserEvent)
        );
      }
    })
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-uf1s7